Different ways to sum
Consider
$$A(x)=\sum_{n,m =2}^{\infty}\frac{ (n-1)(m-1) x^{n+m}}{n (n+1) (n+m) (n+m+1)}$$   where $0<x<1$.    (This slightly different form is obtained by shifting $n \to n-1 $ and $m \to m -1$.)
Using $$\frac{x^{n+m}}{(n+m) (n+m+1)}={1\over x}\int_0^x d y_1 \int_0^{y_1} dy_2 ~ y_2^{n + m - 1},$$ I can get $$A(x)= 6+\left(\frac{6}{x}-3\right) \ln (1-x)+\frac{1}{2} \ln^2(1-x).$$
But I wonder if there is a simpler (or more general) method, based on $e.g.,$ the residue theorem?

You may denote $n+m=k$ and take a coefficient of $x^k$, it is a sum over $n=2, 3,...,n-2$, for which you may use a partial fractions decomposition

@FedorPetrov Thanks. Do you mean =2,3,...,k−2? Using a partial fraction decomposition does not appear to simplify the computation – could you please elaborate?

Denoting $B(x)=6+\left(\frac{6}{x}-3\right) \ln (1-x)+\frac{1}{2} \ln^2(1-x)$ we may check directly that the coefficient of $x^0$ in $B(x)$ equals 0 (aswell as in $A(x)$), and for $k\geqslant 1$ the coefficient of $x^k$ in $B(x)$ equals
$$
-\frac6{k+1}+\frac3{k}+\frac12\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1{j(k-j)}=-3\frac{k-1}{k(k+1)}+\frac12\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1k\left(\frac1j+\frac1{k-j}\right)\\=
-3\frac{(k-1)}{k(k+1)}+\frac1k\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1{j}=:q_k.
$$
In $A(x)$ the coefficient of $x^k$ equals (here I take the summation over $n,m$ not from 2 but from 1 to $\infty$, this does not change the sum $A(x)$, and take the pairs $(n,m)$ with $n+m=k$, i.e., $m=n-k-1$)
$$
\frac1{k(k+1)}\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{(n-1)(k-n-1)}{n(n+1)}
=\frac1{k(k+1)}\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{(n-1)((k+1)-n-2)}{n(n+1)}\\
=\frac1{k(k+1)}(k+1)\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{n-1}{n(n+1)}-\frac1{k(k+1)}\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{n^2+n-2}{n(n+1)}=\\
\frac1{k}\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac2{n+1}-\frac1n\right)-
\frac1{k(k+1)}\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac2n+\frac2{n+1}\right)\\=
\frac1k\left(-2+\frac2k+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac1n\right)-\frac1{k(k+1)}\left(k-1-2+\frac2k\right)\\
=\frac1k\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac1n+\frac1k\left(-2+\frac2k-\frac{k-3}{k+1}-\frac2{k(k+1)}\right)\\
\frac1k\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac1n+\frac1k\left(-2-\frac{k-3}{k+1}+\frac2{k+1}\right)=\frac1k\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac1n-3\frac{(k-1)}{k(k+1)}=q_k
$$
